# Set background of DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker, background-color

How can I fill the background of drop down calender of a DateTimePicker with gradients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTimePicker` is a standard win32 control, that doesn't (AFAIK) have any support for this. Your best option would be to look for a different control that *does* support this type of use - of perhaps switch to WPF, where things are a lot more customizable.